# I am a newbie to c# and ASP.NET Core. I have an issue with connection of my web application to PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, connection

I am developing a simple test web application with registration and ability to log in. I try to add a new row to the database via Postman using this POST request:

```
https://localhost:7239/api/Auth/Register
```

But I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApplication1.Data.AppDbContext' while attempting to activate 'WebApplication1.Controllers.AuthController'.

```
   at lambda_method13(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The database is up and running.

Here is my `AuthController.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1.Data;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public AuthController(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Users.Add(user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Ok("User registered successfully.");
            }
            return BadRequest("Invalid model state.");
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(User user)
        {
            var existingUser = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == user.Username && u.Password == user.Password);

            if (existingUser != null)
            {
                return Ok("Login successful.");
            }

            return BadRequest("Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }
}
```

`AppDbContext.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : DbContext(options)
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Part of `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=database;Username=postgres;Password=qwertyps4;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And finally model `User.cs`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have checked all the files several times, but I just can't figure out the problem.
**Here is the full exception message:**
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApplication1.Data.AppDbContext' while attempting to activate 'WebApplication1.Controllers.AuthController'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ThrowHelperUnableToResolveService(Type type, Type requiredBy)
at lambda_method13(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That all looks correct to me. You've got `services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>()` in the startup.

Comment: Does the exception have an inner exception, or any other additional details?  It could be failing to create the DB Context for any number of reasons.

Comment: I will paste full exception message at the end of the Question

Answer (score 0):

Modify your AppContext.cs to this and add a parameterless constructor.

```
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
 {
    // Constructor with DbContextOptions
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    // Parameterless constructor
    public AppDbContext()
    {
    }
   
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it haven't helped me :( I still get the same exception

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: /* just use this. */ 
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
 {
    // Constructor with DbContextOptions
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}